# Finding Hofstadter's Q-Sequence very slow

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, difference-equations

I'm trying to find [Hofstadter's Q-Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence).

I tried:

```
RSolve[{Q[n] == Q[n - Q[n - 1]] + Q[n - Q[n - 2]], Q[1] == 1, Q[2] == 1}, Q[n], n]
```

but it doesn't work.

Then I tried:

```
Q[1] := 1
Q[2] := 1
Q[n_] := Q[n - Q[n - 1]] + Q[n - Q[n - 2]]

Table[Q[n], {n, 15}]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10}

but it works very slowly.

I want to plot first 200 terms of Q-Sequence but there is no answer...

```
ListPlot[Table[Q[n]/n, {n, 200}]]
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest a duplicate of this question to mark as the original?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Proper [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) is the key:

```
Q[1] = 1;
Q[2] = 1;
Q[n_] := Q[n] = Q[n - Q[n - 1]] + Q[n - Q[n - 2]]

data = Table[Q[n]/n, {n, 10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.051379, Null}

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]